# open API generated Cloud SDK custom fields update

Tags: java, sap-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to update cloudSDKCustomFields using an OpenAPI generated API. But I'm not able to do so as these custom fields are not getting serialized.

How to update these custom fields?

I tried via PATCH and PUT, both not working.

Comment: As a workaround I have added the field which I wanted to update as a property in the updateObject(by making change in yaml file), instead of sending as cloudSDKCustomField. Using PUT.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 4.15.0 of the SAP Cloud SDK, the objects generated by our OpenAPI generator allow you to access custom fields that are not part of the object specification.
Compare for that: https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes#4150---may-26-2023

However, this does not allow you to write custom fields at this moment.

I can create a BLI on our side to have a look into supporting this, but cannot give any timeline or commitment.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, since [version 5.2.0 of the SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes#520---january-22-2024), OpenAPI generated objects can now write custom fields which are not part of the object's schema:

```
setCustomField("nameOfField", "valueOfField")
```